# Parse Deserialize JSON array in ASP.NET Core View Page

Tags: c#, arrays, json, asp.net-core

I have a `JSON` Array String. I want to deserialize it and want to fetch each element in Asp.Net Core view page. 
I have tried it with the `array split` method but it is returning with the [] at first and end. Please help me to solve this.

**My Data is :**

```
[
    "a0xctflnmzfkxqibwgli.png",
    "hjivmkuk2jafe2cfllpv.jpg",
    "i2zcbw0se2btbiq7l4u6.gif",
    "a0rzmnbjnbtvmdv1osxo.jpg",
    "p5ok5a0ozni7lqlvoov2.gif"
]
```

**Required Output :**

```
a0xctflnmzfkxqibwgli.png     
hjivmkuk2jafe2cfllpv.jpg     
i2zcbw0se2btbiq7l4u6.gif     
p5ok5a0ozni7lqlvoov2.gif
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

presumably...

```
string[] values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string[]>(json);
```

(using Json.NET)

Comment: I tried your code but it gives me the following error.

Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: [. Path '', line 1, position 1.

Comment: @MohammedAltaf I did actually *run* the code before posting it... it works fine. Are you sure you copied it correctly? did you perhaps do `DeserializObject<string>(json)` ?

Comment: Thanks It worked

Comment: Answer :var json = productmodel.Product.ProductImages;
    string[] values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string[]>(json);            
    foreach (var image in values)
    {
        @image;
    }